# Don't understand this AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'isalpha'

Tags: python, dataframe, isalpha

**Refer the following code**

```
# import
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import string 

# create data frame
data = {'Name': ['Jas,on', 'Mo.lly', 'Ti;na', 'J:ake', '!Amy', "Myself"]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Name'])
df

# get cleanName - Function
def getCleanName(pName):
    vRetVals = pName.translate(str.maketrans(" ", " ", string.punctuation))
    return(vRetVals)  

# clean Name
print("PreClean Good Rows", df.shape[0] - df.Name.map(lambda v:v.isalpha()).sum())
df['Name'] = [getCleanName for n in df.Name]
print("PostClean Good Rows", df.shape[0] - df.Name.map(lambda v: v.isalpha()).sum())
```

**Issue**

When the below line is run for the first time, it runs properly:

```
print("PreClean Good Rows", df.shape[0] - df.Name.map(lambda v: v.isalpha()).sum())
```

when the same line is run for the second time, it gives the following error

```
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'isalpha'
```

Any ideas, what is causing the issue?

Comment: Where you have `[getCleanName for n in df.Name]`, perhaps you mean `[getCleanName(n) for n in df.Name]`. Otherwise you are just putting a load of references to the function into a list, instead of calling the function.

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to call `getCleanName`, so your `list` ends up a bunch of identical references to the function. Change it to:

```
df['Name'] = [getCleanName(n) for n in df.Name]
#                         ^^^ changed
```

to actually call the function and use the results.